# How to select all records form three tables having following relation

Tags: mysql, relational-database, one-to-many

Place => PID (PK), Name ...

Tag => TID (PK), TagName ...

TagPlaceRelation => ID (PK), PID (FK) , TID (FK) Many to many relations

how to get all Place records along with all its tags

I have tried following query and it return all places record but it only includes first tag associated with with each place which is not required. How can i get all tags of a place along with place data.

```
SELECT p.PID, t.TagName     
FROM Place p    
LEFT JOIN TagPlaceRelation  tp ON p.PID= tp.PID    
LEFT JOIN Tag t ON tp.TID=t.TID    
ORDER BY p.ID
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample.

Comment: The above query should return all tags associated with all places.

Comment: I agree, there's nothing in that query that will limit the number of tags.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. If i remove order by Claus then i can see all palces with tags associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.PID, t.TagName 
  FROM Place p LEFT JOIN TagPlaceRelation tp ON p.PID= tp.PID 
    LEFT JOIN Tag t ON tp.TID=t.TID;
```

This will now get all places with tags. Now if we have place1 having 3 tags then place1 will be repeated three times with tags one by one